# Magento permission error after clearing cache

Tags: magento-1.9

when I clear the cache, I get this following error:

`Error in file: "/var/www/public_html/app/code/local/Wyomind/Simplegoogleshopping/sql/simplegoogleshopping_setup/mysql4-install-5.0.0.php" - Please make sure that / is writable by web-server.`

Then after 20-30 sec, my site is working normally again.

The files have permission 777.

Tried to change the whole path to 777, but that didn't help.

Comment: have u tried to give 777 permissions to var folder??

Comment: I already have 777 on var

Comment: what is owner group of var folder?

Comment: ec2-user apache, using aws ec2

Comment: Is your cloud front is enabled?

Comment: No it is not enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66003/discussion-between-chris-gudn-and-pavan-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into an issue where when the cache was cleared, or any of the magento cli commands ran, the owner settings of directiories and files was changing. Make sure files/directories are owned and writeable by the web server user group.

Comment: I just checked when I cleared the cache now, the owner did not change. And I checked the permission also, nothing changed.

Comment: Are they owned by the web server group, though? Initially when we deployed, owner/group was ourUser:OurUserGroup, we had to change it to ourUser:WebServerGroup, and make sure our user was added to that group

Comment: Our user is ec2-user and server is apache, so ec2-user:apache